# Send push notification from one android app to another using Amazon SNS

Tags: android, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon SNS for push message in my android app. I want to send push messages from one android app/device to another and I am not able to find any documentation for this. Is there a way I can send upstream message to the server from a device/app which will be delivered to another device.